# Can the host-local CNI IPAM plugin be configured to use a node's PodCIDR?

Tags: kubernetes, containers

I am experimenting with [the built-in CNI plugins](https://www.cni.dev/plugins/current/), and I'm unclear about the `host-local` IPAM plugin. The examples show the plugin being manually configured with the subnet to use for a node, this works as expected.

Is it possible to configure this plugin to use a node's `podCIDR` as the host-local subnet?

This would make it suitable for cluster-wide IPAM some other controller allocates disjoint `podCIDR`s to each node, and then the host-local IPAM plugin allocates individual IP addresses to pods.